# Is switching 3G/4G off to save power a cheap trick?

Tags: iphone, ipad, battery, 4g, cellular-data

Since UMTS is a lot fast than EDGE, data transfers via UMTS take less time.
When downloading the same file, it would take longer to be downloaded via EDGE.

- Doesn't the difference in transfer time (partly) kill the advantage of saving power as the antenna pulls power for longer to end the transfer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still want to be downloading stuff, then probably yes, switching off 3G probably won't save you much power / battery life. However, when my battery is running low, switching off 3G can make the difference between the battery making it until I get to a charger or not. Obviously in those conditions I stop surfing or doing anything data-related as well, but even just for being in standby and receiving or making calls, 3G uses a lot more power than GPRS / EDGE / UMTS.